# Can't POST or PATCH on server, got 403 forbidden with api-platform

Tags: symfony, csrf, api-platform.com, lexikjwtauthbundle

I have an issue since several days.

I'm creating an API with *Symfony 5* and *Api-platform*.

I add a JWT auth with *LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle*. I have no problem for register, login or **GET** my entity.

When I start the API on my computer I can **POST** and **PATCH** on localhost without any problem but when I want to **POST** or **PATCH** an entity on my server I always have this response :

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Forbidden</h1>
    <p>You don't have permission to access this resource.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I have this response if I send a request with a valid token or without any token.

Maybe it is a problem with CORS or CSRF ? But I can't find a solution.

Does someone have an idea ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: It’s not a problem with CORS

Comment: Thank you, but do you have an other idea ?

Comment: did you generate certificates for jwt in server?

Comment: Yes. I try to regenerate one with passphrase and one without passphrase but it is not working better !

Comment: do you have voter oder something like "is_granted(
ROLE_ADMIN')" in your code?Can you paste your JWT, maybe a role issue

Answer (score 1):

For those who want the solution, the problem was the server configuration. A firewall blocked all requests other than GET.